# Frame in Tkinter is not recognised even though it's defined

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I am adding a scroll bar to my tkinter application. My Tkinter application already contains multiple frames which you can switch between. In order to add a scroll bar on the `HomePage`, I have created a `main_frame` and a `canvas`, added the scroll bar to the `canvas` and created another frame inside the `canvas` called `second_frame`. The scroll bar has appeared, however another part of my application is that on the `Add_page`, the user clicks a button and an image etc. appears on the `Home_page` or in this case appears in the `second_frame`. My problem is, since the `second_frame` etc. is defined on the `HomePage` only, the `Add_page` does not recognise it and I get an error message stating that `name 'second_frame' is not defined`. I need to somehow ensure that these variables are recognised across all frames. Also, I have removed the `StartPage`, `ToDoPage` and `TimetablePage` from the sample reduce the size of the code.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import strftime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date

x = 200
y = 250
c = 460
d = 290
e = 325
f = 355
g = 390
h = 420
i = 460
j = 490



#calendar and display in label

#window = Tk()

#window.title("StudyFriendO")

IMAGE_PATH = 'apple.png'
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 24)
SMALL_FONT=("Verdana", 12)

class StudyFriendO(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("StudyFriendO") #naming window title
        self.geometry('850x830') #size of window

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       

        #### ADDED
        self.shared_data = {  # Variables shared by all pages.
            'name': tk.StringVar(value=''),
            'assessment': tk.StringVar(value=''),
            'due_date': tk.StringVar(value='')
          
        }

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, HomePage, ToDoPage, TimetablePage, AddPage): #list of multiple frames of program
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)



    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def set_date(self, cont):
        #frame: StartPage = self.frames[cont]
        #frame.date_label.config(text="Today's date is " + datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from
        frame2: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
        frame2.date_label.config(text= datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) #function to get date from

    def getname(self, cont): #FUNCTION WHICH GRABS NAME FROM TEXT ENTRY
        frame2: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
####     frame2.name_label.configure(text=nameentry.get() + "'s Planner ")
        frame2.name_label.configure(text=self.shared_data['name'].get() + "'s Planner ")


    def step(self):
        self.frames[HomePage].my_progress['value']+= 5
        

    def display(self, cont):
        frame2: HomePage = self.frames[HomePage]
        #blue box
        global x , y , c , d , e , f , g, h, i, j
        box_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='apple.png')
        frame2.panel2 = tk.Label(second_frame, image=box_image, bg='#f7f6f6')
        frame2.panel2.image = box_image
        frame2.panel2.place(x=x, y=y)
        x=x
        y = y+260
        #assessment name
        frame2.n = tk.Label(frame2, text="", bg="#e0f6fc", font=60)
        frame2.n.place(x=c, y=d, anchor='center')
        frame2.n.configure(text=self.shared_data['assessment'].get())
        c=c
        d=d+260
    
        #due date
        frame2.d = tk.Label(frame2, text="Due:", bg="#e0f6fc", font=SMALL_FONT)
        frame2.d.place(x=c, y=e, anchor='center')
        c=c
        e=e+260
        
        #cal date
        frame2.c= tk.Label(frame2, text="", bg="#e0f6fc", font=SMALL_FONT)
        frame2.c.place(x=c, y=f, anchor='center')
        frame2.c.configure(text=self.shared_data['due_date'].get())
        c=c
        f=f+260
        
        #no. of days
        plum = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        date_format = "%m/%d/%y"
        a = datetime.strptime(plum, date_format)
        pear = self.shared_data['due_date'].get()
        b = datetime.strptime(pear, date_format)
        delta = b - a
        frame2.days = tk.Label(frame2, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="#e0f6fc")
        frame2.days.place(x=c, y=g, anchor='center')
        c=c
        g=g+260
        
        frame2.days.config(text=delta.days)
        frame2.no_of_days=tk.Label(frame2, text="DAYS",bg="#e0f6fc")
        frame2.no_of_days.place(x=c, y=h, anchor='center')
        c=c
        h=h+260
        
        #progress bar
        frame2.my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(frame2, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='determinate')
        frame2.my_progress.place(x=c, y=i, anchor='center')
        c=c
        i=i+260
        
        frame2.my_button = tk.Button(frame2, text="Progress", command=self.step)
        frame2.my_button.place(x=c, y=j, anchor='center')
        c=c
        j=j+260
        
        


class HomePage(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #### creating scrollbar ####
        
        #create a main frame
        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='#f7f6f6')
        main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        #create a canvas
        my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame, bg='#f7f6f6')
        my_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

        #add a scroll bar to the canvas
        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        #create another frame inside the canvas
        second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)

        # add that new frame to a window in the canvas
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw", width="10000") 


        
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font = LARGE_FONT)
        #label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #height of Y
        tk.Label(main_frame, text="", fg="white", bg="#99cbd8").place(anchor='w', relheight=2, width='150') #ipadx=73)

        #width of x
        frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg="#c0e3ed", height=110)
        frame.place(anchor='n', relwidth=2)
        #LABEL WHICH DISPLAYS NAME FROM TEXT ENTRY
        #tk.Label(self, text ="Name's Planner", fg="white", bg="#c0e3ed", font = LARGE_FONT).place(relx=0.5, y=50, anchor='center')
        self.name_label = tk.Label(main_frame, text="", font=("Arial Bold", 40), bg="#c0e3ed")
        self.name_label.place(relx=0.55, y=55, anchor='center')

        self.date_label = tk.Label(second_frame, text="", bg="#c0e3ed")
        # keep placing the label at top right corner
        self.date_label.place(relx=1, y=0, anchor='ne')
        #pack(side='top', anchor='ne')



        button1 = tk.Button(main_frame, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=145)

        button1 = tk.Button(main_frame, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="To Do", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ToDoPage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=225)
        #(relx=0.2, rely=0.4, anchor='center')

        button1 = tk.Button(main_frame, height=2, width=10, bg="#e0f6fc", text="Timetable", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TimetablePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.place(x=35, y=305)

        

        photo2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='apple.png') #photo1 is a variable
        #label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        panel = tk.Label(main_frame, image = photo2)
        panel.image = photo2
        panel.place(x=35, y=400)
        


        #your upcoming assesments title
        title = tk.Label(main_frame, text="Your Upcoming Assesments", bg='#f7f6f6', font=LARGE_FONT)
        title.place(x=200, y=150)

        add_button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text="Add", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AddPage))
        add_button.place(relx=0.8, rely=1, anchor='se')

        save_button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text="Save")
        save_button.place(relx=0.9, rely=1, anchor='se')
    
        clear_button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text="Clear")
        clear_button.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor='se')



        self.configure(bg='#f7f6f6')



class AddPage(tk.Frame):

        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)



                #width of x
        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="#c0e3ed", height=110)
        frame.pack(fill="x")
        
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Add Assesment", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="#c0e3ed")
        label.place(relx=0.5, y=50, anchor='center')



        assessment_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter assesment name:")
        assessment_label.place(relx=0.5, y=200, anchor='center')

        assessment_name = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['assessment'])
        assessment_name.place(relx=0.5, y=220, anchor='center')


        cal2 = Calendar(self, textvariable=controller.shared_data['due_date'], background="#e0f6fc", disabledbackground="white", bordercolor="light blue", headersbackground="light blue", normalbackground="#e0f6fc", foreground="black", normalforeground='black', headersforeground='white', selectmode="day", year=2021, month=8, day=9)
        cal2.place(relx=0.5, y=400, anchor='center')

        due_date = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit")
        due_date.place(relx=0.5, y=510, anchor='center')


        add_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Add Assesment", command=lambda: controller.display(HomePage))
        add_button.place(relx=0.5, y=560, anchor='center')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HomePage)) #button to navigate page
        button1.pack()




app = StudyFriendO()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you further reduce the code to reproduce the problem? Please leave out the lines that aren't necessary instead of commenting them out! Thanks :)

Comment: Your problem is that you define `second_frame` as a local variable in `HomePage.__init__`.

Comment: How do I not define it as a local variable?

Comment: Alternatives to local variables are (1) `global` declaration or (2) combining it with `self.` in member functions (`self` is the first parameter of those functions).